# How to change the color of text in javafx TextField?

Tags: javafx

I want to change font color in TextField .I found `-fx-background-color` , `-fx-border-color` for changing the color of background and border but nothing for text.

Answer (score 59):

Setting the `-fx-text-fill` works for me.

See below:

```
if (passed) {
    resultInfo.setText("Passed!");
    resultInfo.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green; -fx-font-size: 16px;");
} else {
    resultInfo.setText("Failed!");
    resultInfo.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-font-size: 16px;");
}
```

Answer (score 37):

The CSS styles for text input controls such as TextField for JavaFX 8 are defined in the [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) stylesheet as below.  Create a custom CSS stylesheet and modify the colors as you wish.  Use the [CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) if you need help understanding the syntax and available attributes and values.

```
.text-input {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
    -fx-highlight-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-20%);
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
    -fx-cursor: text;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.583em 0.333333em 0.583em; /* 4 7 4 7 */
}
.text-input:focused {
    -fx-highlight-fill: -fx-accent;
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: 
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 4, 0;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}
```

Although using an external stylesheet is a preferred way to do the styling, you can style inline, using something like below:

```
textField.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
```

Comment: I have Color object. How can I change textfield color using this?

Comment: @alhelal convert the color object to a string using the method here: [How to get hex web String from JavaFX ColorPicker color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925318/how-to-get-hex-web-string-from-javafx-colorpicker-color), then set the color to the string you derived:  `textField.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: " + colorString + ";");`

Answer (score 10):

If you are designing your Javafx application using `SceneBuilder` then use `-fx-text-fill`(if not available as option then write it in style input box) as style and give the color you want,it will change the text color of your `Textfield`.

I came here for the same problem and solved it in this way.