# How to change font colour inside a text field javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a text field in javaFX and anything typed in that field must appear in blue color, can that be achieved via css?if yes, then how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of text in javafx TextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702542/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-javafx-textfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS you can try :

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

**EDIT**

Alright, your question seems to be duplicate with that one : [How to change the color of text in javafx TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702542/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-javafx-textfield)

Try this :

```
textField.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: blue;");
```

Comment: Yes, of course it is ; ) -> https://jsfiddle.net/7yc8sbpo/

May you post your code in the description of your question?

Comment: i want to apply that for javafx,my textfield id is "name" whatever being typed in that should appear in blue like: #name:focused{ colour:blue; } @AdrienLeber