# How can I change CSS atributes of a parent stage in a program through a settings stage?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a JavaFX program and I would like the settings window to change the properties of the parent window for example like a background color, but I would like it to take effect when the setting window is closed.

I tried editing the parent CSS file through a method I created in the controller class.
However, editing the parent CSS file needs the program to be rerun to take effect but I would like it to work right away.

Comment: Related [dynamically colored window with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087164/javafx-dynamically-colored-window-with-css/58107552#58107552).

Comment: [mcve] please .. without we can't know what _exactly_ you tried and what could possibly have gone wrong