# How to convert color from ColorPicker to String value in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, colors

I want to make the user choose the color using the ColorPicker, and then use that color to change the color of a button. JavaFX

```java
    ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker();
            cp.setOnAction(e -> {
                Color c = cp.getValue();
                System.out.println(c);
            });
```

In the println it will give answers like 0xe6e64dff,0xccffccff...

And if i want to color the button in say, blue, i would need to use this:

```java
    Button button = new Button();
    button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff0000; ");
```

So i assume i would have to convert the color value to a String before i can use it  ? Or how do i go about this ?
How do i get the picked color to be usable in the setStyle line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get hex web String from JavaFX ColorPicker color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925318/how-to-get-hex-web-string-from-javafx-colorpicker-color)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Converting `Color` to Hex String

You can use the following to create a hex string from a `Color`:

```java
private static String toHexString(Color color) {
  int r = ((int) Math.round(color.getRed()     * 255)) << 24;
  int g = ((int) Math.round(color.getGreen()   * 255)) << 16;
  int b = ((int) Math.round(color.getBlue()    * 255)) << 8;
  int a = ((int) Math.round(color.getOpacity() * 255));
  return String.format("#%08X", (r + g + b + a));
}
```

This will also include the alpha (i.e. opacity) of the color. Note that the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) does not document any support for 4-digit/8-digit hex values:

> **RGB Hex:** The format of an RGB value in hexadecimal notation is a ‘#’ immediately followed by either three or six hexadecimal characters. The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies on the color depth of the display.

However, the documentation of [`Color#web(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#web(java.lang.String)) says the following format is supported:

> An HTML long or short format hex string with **an optional hex alpha channel** *[emphasis added]*. Hexadecimal values may be preceded by either `"0x"` or `"#"` and can either be 2 digits in the range `00` to `0xFF` or a single digit in the range `0` to `F`.

Also note it says the hexadecimal value may be prefixed with *either* `0x` or `#`.

Here's an example using the above utility method:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
    root.getChildren().add(picker);
    picker.setOnAction(
        event -> {
          event.consume();

          Color value = picker.getValue();
          if (value == null) {
            root.setStyle(null);
          } else {
            String style = String.format("-fx-background-color: %s;", toHexString(value));
            root.setStyle(style);
          }
        });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Color to Hexadecimal Example");
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private static String toHexString(Color color) {
    int r = ((int) Math.round(color.getRed()     * 255)) << 24;
    int g = ((int) Math.round(color.getGreen()   * 255)) << 16;
    int b = ((int) Math.round(color.getBlue()    * 255)) << 8;
    int a = ((int) Math.round(color.getOpacity() * 255));

    return String.format("#%08X", (r + g + b + a));
  }
}
```

---

## Background Property

There is another way to accomplish what you're doing. Instead of setting the `style`, which requires converting the `Color` to a `String`, you can set the [`Region#background`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty) property directly. Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
    root.getChildren().add(picker);
    picker.setOnAction(
        event -> {
          event.consume();

          Color value = picker.getValue();
          if (value == null) {
            root.setBackground(null);
          } else {
            root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(value, null, null)));
          }
        });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Programmatically Set Background Color Example");
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer:

```
            cp.setOnAction(e -> {
            Color c = cp.getValue();
            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + c.toString().replace("0x", "#"));
            System.out.println(c);
        });
```

Comment: Don’t use `toString()` for functionality like this. The [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#toString()) explicitly states it is “only to be used for informational purposes”. Use the solution in the question linked in the comment below the question.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't actually that complicated when you simply need to take the color value generated from a JavaFX ColorPicker and assign it to a CSS property.

in the OnAction event of the ColorPicker, add this code to ensure you extract the first three pairs of hex values, then format them back into a CSS friendly format like this:

```
String colorString = String.valueOf(colorPicker.getValue());
String regex = "([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(colorString);
StringBuilder cssFormat = new StringBuilder();
if (m.find()) {
    cssFormat.append("#").append(m.group(0)).append(";");
}
```

In this example, the String called cssFormat will then be able to be inserted into the style of whatever JavaFX object you need to assign it to. Here is how you would do that using a Button as the OP requested:

```
if (!cssFormat.isEmpty()) {
  button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + cssFormat);
}
```

It's literally that easy.

If you need to convert that String back into a color, you do it like this:

```
Color color = Color.valueOf(colorString);
```

:-)

Comment: from Color.toString doc: _This method is intended to be used only for informational purposes. The content and format of the returned string might vary between implementations._ ... Or in other words: __don't__ use toString for application reasons

Comment: @kleopatra - I changed it ... is that any better?

Comment: no - the error is the same as the first version, now disguised by String.valueOf (which is implemented to use .. guess what?) plus some smoke by pattern matching.

Comment: Using `Color#toString()` would certainly be easier, but as pointed out, the documentation explicitly says the output is essentially only meant for debugging. Though I doubt they will change the implementation any time soon. However, I don't see how your (failed) attempt to avoid `#toString()` is any easier/clearer than the accepted (my) answer. If you don't like the bit manipulation, then perhaps you (or someone else) could submit a feature request for a `Color#toHexColorString()` method to be added, assuming such a request doesn't already exist.